# How to find issue on remote server that you don't have access to?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting

Ok, so this is my dilemma...  I have an ASP.NET MVC site that is running into some conditions that it is pegging the processor on the iss boxes it's running on.  I don't have access to these servers (it's a farm of about 5 iis6 boxes behind a netscalar).  I am doing some logging to a sql database, but the problem is that when the cpu pegs my database starts timing out.  The iis servers are hosted in house, but I can't get access to them.

And to make things ever more complicated, I can't reproduce any of these issues in my qa environment (which I don't have access to either).  QA is setup to similarly to our prod environment, but it runs on a single box that isn't behind a netscalar.

So, any thoughts on the best way to try to track down where my issues lie?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already logging to a database, why you don't log to another database, install this DB on another computer, so that when your MVC application starts killing the CPU the database won't be affected (since it is working on another computer).

or you could log to an FTP folder that you can access.

Hope I helped.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... the problem (as far as I can tell) isn't the db itself, but rather the iis box being unresponsive and timing out on the db calls.  The db is already hosted elsewhere, so I don't think that would help much.  I will look into dumping log files to disk space, I will have to check to see if I can get a space for that...

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Trace.   Haven't used MVC, but I'm assuming it still works...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I would, but since it's a production server they don't want us to have trace enabled.

Comment: LOL... this is classic IT foolishness.  YOUR SERVER IS NOT WORKING CORRECTLY.  Do they want it fixed or not?  I know a way to also solve this problem and use 100% less electricity in the data center!  Turn off the server.  This can also save hundreds of thousands of dollars in employee salaries!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is going on with the system you could read from the event viewer programatically:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815314
This should help you to learn what is going on with the system.  This way you can build a web interface for it and capture any info you may want to look at for what is going.